# dajaxice: passing an argument to a python function

Tags: ajax, django, dajaxice

Using Dajaxice I want to pass a parameter to a python function.

In the html file I have the following statement

```
<a href="#" onclick="Dajaxice.myapp.sayhello(Dajax.process,{'dir':3} )"> <i class="icon"></i></a>
```

and in my ajax.ps file I have the function

```
@dajaxice_register
def sayhello(request, dir):
    print(dir)
```

It works fine if I remove the second argument dir in both the html and the python file, but with having dir, I get the error message "Something goes wrong".

Does anybody know what could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried to specify `method='GET'` for your sayhello function in the decorator? Just to check.

Comment: hm, I think you have a point here. If I register it with method='GET'  I get the error message: 
    dajaxice_register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'. Do you know why this is? It looks like the installation might be flawed?

Comment: That is strange. Do you know where this exception occurs in the call stack? And what version of dajaxice are you using? On the latest GitHub code I don't see such exception, unless I missed something.

Comment: maybe it works only with strings, try: `{'dir': '3'}`

Comment: You could use JSON.stringify(data) as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Python 3.*,  then in module dajaxIce make the changes file venv/lib/python3.2/site-packages/dajaxice/views.py

```
    def safe_dict(d):
        """
        Recursively clone json structure with UTF-8 dictionary keys
        http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/684379
        """
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            return dict([(k, safe_dict(v)) for k, v in d.items()])
        elif isinstance(d, list):
            return [safe_dict(x) for x in d]
        else:
            return d
```

Answer (score 0):

change the sayhello to :

```
def sayhello(request):
  my_dict=json.loads(request.POST['argv'])
  dir=my_dict['dir']
  print(dir)
```